# syntax highlighting for .ru files in textmate

Tags: ruby, textmate, rack, textmatebundles

I am using text mate on the mac whilst learning Ruby on Rails. However the backup files (.ru) don't have any syntax highlighting and I can't find any bundles for these for text mate. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Btw this files are the "rackup" files. Your (rack-compatible) web server will search for this file and start every application inside defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just select Ruby from the bottom bar select menu or hit ⌃⌥⇧R (Control + Option + Shift + R):

[image]

---

And for saving this preference permanently, go to Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Edit Languages ... -> Ruby and here search for an Array called **fileTypes** and add `'ru'` to it:

[image]